# Rotation repetition animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, rotation

I'd like to animate a UIImageView left and right. My goal is quite simple:

I have an image, I'd like to rotate it slightly to the left with an angle of .pi/8 and then from that rotated position, rotate it back to -pi/8. I want to repeat these rotations three times and stop. The image has to be in a non-rotated state initially.

I was able to achieve it by doing this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.4, options: [], animations: {
                    self.imageView.rotate(angle: .pi/9)
                }, completion: { _ in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                        self.imageView.rotate(angle: -.pi/7)
                    }, completion: { _ in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                            self.imageView.rotate(angle: .pi/9)
                        }, completion: { _ in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                                self.imageView.rotate(angle: -.pi/7)
                            }, completion: { _ in
                                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                                    self.imageView.rotate(angle: .pi/9)
                                }, completion: { _ in
                                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                                        self.imageView.rotate(angle: -.pi/7)
                                    }, completion: {_ in
                                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
                                            self.giftImageView.rotate(angle: .pi/10.5)
                                        })})})})})})})})
```

However, I believe there is a simpler way to do it but I can't figure it out and the research isn't leading to any simpler solution. After some trial and error, I got to .pi/10.5 to have the image view centered and to not look tilted.

I'd much appreciate your help for a simpler way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is rotation extension function

```
extension UIView {
    func rotation(isClockWise:Bool) {
        let rotation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        if isClockWise {
            rotation.toValue = NSNumber(value:  Double.pi / 8)
        } else {
            rotation.toValue = NSNumber(value:  -Double.pi / 8)
        }
        rotation.duration = 1 // 1 second duration change it to 0.3 or whatever
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = 3 
        self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

then you need to do some work in controller

```
   class ViewController:UIViewController {
        var timer = Timer()
        var isClockWise = false
        var rotationCount = 0
        let imageView = UIImageView()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          view.backgroundColor = .orange
          timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(rotationHandle), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    

       @objc
       func rotationHandle() {
         rotationCount += 1
         if isClockWise {
           imageView.rotation(isClockWise: true)
         } else {
           imageView.rotation(isClockWise: false)
        }
        isClockWise.toggle()
        if rotationCount == 6 {
          timer.invalidate()
          imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
          imageView.transform = .identity
        }
   }
}
```